# how to insert comments into a table, by structfiled from a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to insert the comments of the fields of a table, I'm trying to use the structfield , but it's not working:

My Code:

```
Schema = StructType([
   StructField("id", IntegerType(), True,
   {'description': "Unique id, primary key"}),
   StructField("title", StringType(), True,
   {'description': "Name of the category"})])
```

when I search the table in athena, the comments don't appear, does anyone have any suggestions on how I can comment the fields via pyspark?

```
SELECT * FROM   information_schema.columns
    WHERE  table_schema = 'teste'
    AND table_name = 'teste
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing `'comment'` instead of `'description'`

```
Schema = StructType([
   StructField("id", IntegerType(), True,
   {'comment': "Unique id, primary key"}),
   StructField("title", StringType(), True,
   {'comment': "Name of the category"})])
```